# Getting strange results with PdfDocument on single android device

Tags: android, pdf, text, font-face

In an android app I'm using PdfDocument to save a report to a pdf file. On a customer's device I'm getting a strange result with the text of the report.

The following is image of header with the following text rendered in DroidSansMono:

Baus Demo Company

4727 4TH AVE SW STE 202

Seatle, WA 9816

Tel: 206-932-986

Fax: 206-932-986

[image: Header]

I this same process renders well on most devices. I checked the pdf file and it has the correct font.

here is the full PDF file:
[PDF File](http://www.baus-systems.com/Sales_Invoice_10500012_180511160316.pdf)

Can anyone help me figure out why the text is rendered so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this weird look is that this is exactly the formatting the PDF describes.

#### Horizontal scaling

The content stream of the page consists of three sections:

The top section, all text above the image of a signature, contains at the beginning the instruction

```
2000 Tz
```

Inside the section after some text a `1000 Tz` follows, then again a `2000 Tz` and yet again a `1000 Tz`.

The **Tz** operator sets the horizontal scaling to the preceding number as a percentage value. Thus, these instruction cause all following text (until the end of the section where the graphics state is reset) to be horizontally stretched by a factor of either 10 or 20!

This explains why the glyphs are so wide but not why they overlap so much.

#### Glyph widths and positioning

The reason why they overlap so much is that each glyph is individually positioned at a distance appropriate for a layout without horizontal scaling.

First of all, the **DroidSansMono** font information in the PDF declare that virtually all glyphs in the font have a width of 0. Thus, whenever a glyph is drawn, the text insertion point does not wander along to the glyph's end but remains at its start.

Furthermore, each glyph is drawn using an individual operation and between two such single glyph drawing operations the text insertion point is advanced by a separate instruction. But the distance parameter of this instruction is appropriate for the glyphs without horizontal scaling!

This causes all the overlaps.

---

If this very PDF is rendered "well" (i.e. incorrectly ignoring the **Tz** operations) on most devices, the PDF renderer used on those devices clearly does a lousy job of PDF rendering.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the horizontal scaling would be off by a factor of 1000 for a pdf created on one device and be correct for pdf files made on the others?

Comment: I can only assume there to be a bug either in the underlying `PdfDocument` implementation (Have you checked whether the devices in question have something in common? E.g. the same android version?) or in the application.

Comment: found that the paint textScaleX is broken on some Android 8 devices for the PdfDocuments canvas. I used canvas scale instead.

Comment: Is there a bug on issue tracker for this?